# How to find duration string of hour,minute,seconds?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I find the duration of hour, minute and second in Excel formula?

[image]

Comment: Look at column B and use text functions such as left(), mid() right() and find() to separate the numbers then recalculate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SEARCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) to find the time substring. `SEARCH` allows wildcards, so for example:

```
=SEARCH("??h:??m:??s",A1)
```

`?` replaces any single character, and `A1` is the cell to be searched.

Then, as the length of the string is fixed, use `MID` to return the actual string:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("??h:??m:??s",A1),11)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `FILTERXML()` will best fit to extract duration. Try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'Duration:')]")
```

[image]